# Find out path of a file based on part of its name and directory location in bash script

Tags: bash

I am looking to find out path of a file based on part of its name (knowing the directory) in a bash script

e.g

in /tmp (X is any 0-9/A-Z char):

```
XXX_CAR_XXX
XXX_PLANE_XXX
XXX_BIKE_XXX
etc...
```

in terminal :

```
readlink -f /tmp/*CAR* #--> outputs /tmp/XXX_CAR_XXX
```

in script :
`CAR_PATH=$(readlink -f /tmp/*CAR*)` #--> this doesn't work because of * does not expand, but I don't know how I should do it

or maybe I could use another approach

Thanks !

Comment: I seem to be able to get this to work just fine in a bash script. Perhaps more details on how it's being used in the script would help.

Comment: What it means "doesn't work? what gives `echo "$CAR_PATH"`?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
find /path/to/file -type f -name '*word*'
```